# access image with given dimensions which is given by user

Tags: php

I want access my uploaded image which is uploaded with 1200*2000 dimension.But at access time I want to access it in 200*150(its user given values) dimension in php code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php    it will help you

Comment: add your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that case you have to resize your uploaded image as thump (200*150) and small (400*300) .  this is for jpg and jpeg image .

```
$filename = 'source.jpg';

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$thumb_width = 200;
$thumb_height = 150;

$small_width = 400;
$small_height = 300;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
$small = imagecreatetruecolor($small_width, $small_height);

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize thumb
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height);

// Resize small
imagecopyresized($small, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $small_width, $small_height, $width, $height);

// Output thumb
imagejpeg($thumb, "thumb.jpg");

// Output small
imagejpeg($small, "small.jpg");

//save memory
imagedestroy($thumb); 
imagedestroy($small);
```

Comment: ...........but not working with multiple images only for single image i want to list of images that have size according to me

Comment: please check this code , i have changed for 2 size thumb and small.

Comment: this is working but can you make it dynamic as like image name get from folder and multiple image also?